# Repeating of a preposition in a subclause

Tags: prepositions

I have found this sentence in [an article in NYT:](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/04/business/shrinking-stock-market.html)

> Our visibility into the inner workings of public companies isn’t great, but we know far more about them than we do private companies, which aren’t required to disclose nearly as much information.

Shouldn't be the about preposition repeated before "private companies", so the subclause would be "than we do private companies". I've read rules saying prepositions doesn't have to be repeated in sequence, but I know no rule allowing to omit them in a subclause.

Comment: Other native speakers may disagree with me, but **visibility** is a characteristic not of the seer but of the seen.  We cannot say **Our visibility into ...**.

Comment: Yes, "insight" would be better than "visibility"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to repeat the preposition there, but it would not be ungrammatical to do so.  Sometimes it is advisable to repeat the preposition, such as when there is a list of items, some of which are joined by **and**, and you want to make the relationship clear.

There was [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175137/choice-of-punctuation-which-is-easier-for-the-native-speaker-to-read/175178#175178) recently where this came up.